# I cannot apply display: none to ul

Tags: html, css, display

I have an ul element (one of three on the page) that I don't want to be shown on mobile devices. I'm trying to apply `display: none;` to it but it doesn't work.
The code isn't mine, I just used a template from the internet, so go easy on me, plz

Html part

```
<section id="banner" class="major">
                    <div class="inner">
                                <header class="major">
                                    <h1>This the title</h1>
                                </header>
                                <div class="content">
                                      <p> and some text here </p>  
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li><a href="#one" class="button next scrolly">A button</a></li>
                                    </ul> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
</section>
```

What I have in CSS

```
ul.actions {
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        cursor: default;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: -1em;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

        ul.actions li {
            padding: 0 0 0 1em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        ul.actions.special {
            -moz-justify-content: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: center;
            -ms-justify-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0;
        }

            ul.actions.special li:first-child {
                padding-left: 0;
            }

        ul.actions.stacked {
            -moz-flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-left: 0;
        }

            ul.actions.stacked li {
                padding: 1.3em 0 0 0;
            }

                ul.actions.stacked li:first-child {
                    padding-top: 0;
                }

        ul.actions.fit {
            width: calc(100% + 1em);
        }

            ul.actions.fit li {
                -moz-flex-grow: 1;
                -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
                -ms-flex-grow: 1;
                flex-grow: 1;
                -moz-flex-shrink: 1;
                -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
                -ms-flex-shrink: 1;
                flex-shrink: 1;
                width: 100%;
            }

                ul.actions.fit li > * {
                    width: 100%;
                }

            ul.actions.fit.stacked {
                width: 100%;
            }
```

ul.actions are used for different buttons throughout the page: one that I showed you in the html part and two other buttons to fill out a form.
So, I'm adding this bit of code but it just won't work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            #banner .actions  {
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That code works fine

Comment: It is hiding in mobile devices, It will hide only when max-width is less than 480px. You can resize the window and check

Comment: It's working on screen sizes less than 480px width

Comment: That's weird cause I'm opening my website on different mobile phones and that stupid button is just there! I tried changing the width parameter and everything. I can't figure this out

Comment: Please share website URL, It seems like Something is overriding

Comment: If you are working on localhost, try again after disabling cache. Or you can simply open up css file in browser and refresh it, and open html file again. I hope it will help.

Comment: Well, my website contains my detailed personal info. But here's the template. https://html5up.net/forty I need to get rid of the GET STARTED button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used this code in wrong CSS file.

**Please use right approch:**

Your mentioned URL have this CSS
https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/forty/assets/css/main.css

The media query **@media screen and (max-width: 480px)** is mentioned in this css. Please go there

Please use this bit of code in this media query

```
#banner .actions {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I've been tinkering with this code since last summer and I guess I messed up somewhere along the way. So I simply replaced my main.css with the original one and now `display:none` finally works! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to work fine, I am not sure if you opened the page on the mentioned browsers before doing some code editing. In that case, clearing the caches could help.

Answer (score 0):

That code works fine.

If this is not work fine on you site It seems like any other declaration overriding this declarations.

When an **important rule** is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations.

Please use CSS rule with **!important** and check after Clear your cache.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            #banner .actions  {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share URL.

Comment: https://html5up.net/forty I need to get rid of the GET STARTED button

Comment: You are in wrong CSS. I added a new answer by step by step. It will help you definitely. Please check my new answer.